# How can I execute a python script at the same time another application begins running?

Tags: python, windows, macos, google-chrome

I'm still a novice to Python but I would like my python script to start running the moment I click on the Google Chrome icon to open up chrome. Is it possible for the script to start and run in response to other applications (such as Chrome) being used?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 10, but I also have OS X Yosemite on my mac

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this via the command line:

### Windows

```
C:\Users\path\to\python\script>start chrome & python script.py
```

### OS X

```
$(/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome) & python ~/path/to/file/script.py
```

The [`&`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators) in the command allows you to open Google Chrome (or the web browser of your choosing) in the [background](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175741/what-is-background-and-foreground-processes-in-jobs) while executing your Python script in the [foreground](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175741/what-is-background-and-foreground-processes-in-jobs).

Regarding Chrome specifically, you might also explore [Google startup scripts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript), though it appears that you have to sign up for Google's Cloud services to implement these.

Comment: I guess that would work for testing purposes, but I was more interested if I click on the chrome icon to open chrome I would that action to also execute the python script

Comment: For that specific functionality, it appears that Google Startup Scripts (see my answer) does the trick, but you'll have to sign up for the services, and it only applies to Chrome.  You might consider clarifying your original post.